# Can java create multiple hashsets with loop

Tags: java

if I want to create 3 hashsets will be like:

```
HashSet<String> hashSet1 = new HashSet<String>();
HashSet<String> hashSet2 = new HashSet<String>();
HashSet<String> hashSet3 = new HashSet<String>();
```

so how could I create n hashsets by using a loop?
like

```
HashSet<String> hashSet1 = new HashSet<String>();
HashSet<String> hashSet2 = new HashSet<String>();
HashSet<String> hashSet3 = new HashSet<String>();
...
...
...
HashSet<String> hashSetn = new HashSet<String>();
```

-Thanks

Comment: Put the sets in a `List`.

Comment: Or an array of `n` size.

Answer (score 5):

The following does the trick:

```java
int numberOfMaps = 10;
List<HashSet<String>> hashSetsList = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfMaps; i++) {
    hashSetsList.add(new HashSet<>());
}
```

Or using Java 8 new features:

```java
int numberOfMaps = 10;
List<HashSet<String>> hashSetsList = new ArrayList<>();
IntStream.range(0, numberOfMaps).forEach(i -> hashSetsList.add(new HashSet<>()));
```

or

```java
List<HashSet<String>> hashSetsList = IntStream.range(0, numberOfMaps)
      .mapToObj(i -> new HashSet<String>()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

*(Thanks @magicmn for the input)*

or

```java
List<HashSet<String>> hashSetsList = new ArrayList<>(Stream.generate(() -> new HashSet<String>())
      .limit(numberOfMaps).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

*(Thanks @Elliott Frisch for the input)*

You just need to adjust the `numberOfMaps` value.

Comment: Or `List<HashSet<String>> sets = IntStream.range(0, numberOfMaps).mapToObj(i -> new HashSet<>()).collect(Collectors.toList());` should also work.

Comment: Or `List<HashSet<String>> hashSetsList = new ArrayList<>(Stream.generate(() -> new HashSet<String>()).limit(numberOfMaps).collect(Collectors.toList()));`

Comment: @2333333, did this help? Let me know if something is unclear.